# I am getting Expression Expected; Error ':' expected

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In the line of categoryName : categories.find((category) => category.id === post.categoryId)?.title

Iam getting error Expression Expected; Error ':' expected

```
getPostsWithCategory(){
        return this.getUsers().pipe(mergeMap((posts)=>{
            return this.categoryService.getCategories().pipe(map((categories) =>{
                return posts.map((post) =>{
                  return{
                    ...post,
                    categoryName : categories.find((category) => category.id === post.categoryId)?.title,
                  };
                });
            }));
        }));
      }
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal, Reproducible Example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)? The code looks fine [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yzfcjt?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Try wrapping the `find()` in a bracket: `(categories.find((category) => category.id === post.categoryId))?.title`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using a version of Angular < v9, which doesn't support the TypeScript v3.7 or higher (which includes the extremely popular [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) feature).

So you can't use the optional chaining feature in your `TS` files: **object`?`.property**.

```js
categoryName: categories.find((category) => category.id === post.categoryId)?.title
```

To resolve this issue, you either need to upgrade your project to Angular ≥ v9, or simply replace the optional chaining operator with the following:

```js
// ...
const category = categories.find((category) => category.id === post.categoryId);
return {
  ...post,
  categoryName: category ? category.title : undefined, // OR `category && category.title`
};
```